# How can I pass a list literal to f:selectItems?

Tags: jsf, el, literals, selectmanycheckbox

For example:

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox
    id="literalOptions"
    value="firstOption">
    <f:selectItems value="[firstOption, secondOption, thirdOption]"/>
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

this doesn't work, but you get the idea?

I want to pass literal (string-type) list options (not necessarily but possibly retrieved from a bean property as a String), the `[a,b,c]` list-syntax probably isn't correct, but which is?

Or, alternatively, how can I pass a list literal to a custom component I create that passes this literal to `f:selectItems` which I use internally in my custom component? That is, how can I create a custom component that accepts such a literal for ad hoc definition of list values by the component user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Java EE 6, use [JSTL `fn:split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/fn/split.fn.html) trick.

```
<html ... xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions">
...
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="firstOption">
    <f:selectItems value="#{fn:split('firstOption,secondOption,thirdOption', ',')}"/>
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

If you're on Java EE 7, use [EL 3.0 collection literal](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-el004.htm).

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="firstOption">
    <f:selectItems value="#{['firstOption', 'secondOption', 'thirdOption']}"/>
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

You was close, you just had to quote the string values and to put the whole in `#{...}`.

Note that specifying a literal in `<h:selectManyCheckbox value>` would fail with a `PropertyNotWritableException` on submit, but that's a different problem.

Comment: Although this works wouldn't it be better to not have this kind of 'conplexity' in EL for peformance reasons and do it lazy in a bean?

Comment: @Kukeltje: I'm not seeing performance problems here. However, design wise model values surely belong in the model. But the OP asked so and it's not impossible :)